# Tree logic issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react-checkbox-tree (Reactjs) to have a multiple select tree where I try to give access to users and it should have the following characteristics:

- Select by default when I add an item to it
- Allow max one item or none to be selected for the latest children

So far the functionality is almost done, but I have the following issue:

Choosing an "uncle" unselects the "nephews"
[image]

The function I have to select an uncheck is as follows:

```
onCheckDefaults(checked) {
  let oldCheck = [...this.state.checkedDefaults]
  let difference = checked.filter(x => !oldCheck.includes(x))
  let clean = [...checked]
  if (difference.length > 0) {
    let countParent = difference[0].split("/");
    countParent.pop()
    let parent = countParent.join("/");
    if (oldCheck.length>0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < oldCheck.length; j++) {
          if (typeof(oldCheck[j])!=="undefined") {
            if (oldCheck[j].startsWith(parent + "/")) {
                clean = checked.filter((e, i) => {
                  return e !== oldCheck[j]
                })
              } else {
                clean = checked.filter((e, i) => {
                    if (e.startsWith(parent + "/")) {
                      for (var a in difference) {
                        if (typeof(e)!=="undefined") {
                          return e !== difference[a]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                })
              clean=[...oldCheck,clean[0]]
              }
          }
        }
      this.setState({
        checkedDefaults: clean,
      }, () => {
        this.addDefaults(clean)
      })
    } else {
      if (checked.length>1) {
        checked = checked.filter((e, i) => {
            if (e.startsWith(parent + "/")) {
              for (var a in difference) {
                return e !== difference[a]
              }
            }
        })
      }
      this.setState({
        checkedDefaults: checked,
      }, () => {
        this.addDefaults(checked)
      })
    }
} else {
  this.setState({
    checkedDefaults: checked,
  }, () => {
    this.addDefaults(checked)
  })
}}
```

Thank you!